# In HDLC, how to recognize bit stuffing?

Tags: protocol-theory, layer2

In framing for the HDLC protocol, assume the receiver receives the following string of bits:

```
[…] 011111010 […]
```

How can it realize whether the sequence “011111010” is real data, or the result of a bit stuffing operation from an original flag-like sequence “ 01111110”?

Comment: Has any answer solved your question? Then please accept it or your question will keep popping up here forever. Please also consider voting for useful answers.

Answer (score 0):

Bit stuffing is used in synchronous HDLC when *five* consecutive `1` of user data have been transmitted. A `0` is inserted to prevent more than five `1` - even if a `0` was following anyway.

The receiver needs to remove a stuffed `0` after five `1`, not after four like in your example (before editing).

Since you've edited your question to include five consecutive `1` now: yes, there's a stuffed `0`, the user data is `[…] 01111110 […]`

If six `1` are received it's a frame delimiter (*flag*) .

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Indeed, the sequence I wanted to use is "011111010." Indeed, after receiving sequence "011111010," the receiver may think that the intermediate 0 is the result of bit-stuffing, so it reverts sequence "01111110" which is NOT interpreted as a flag but as real data. My question is: what if "011111010" is already my real data? How should I force the receiver not to "remove" the intermediate 0?

Comment: After `11111` there's always a `0` inserted, so `111110` becomes `1111100`. `011111010` becomes `0111110010`.